# SFTP cannot rename files but FTP is OK

Tags: ftp, sftp, synology, cyberduck

I have enabled both SFTP and FTP on my Synology NAS. Using CyberDuck, both SFTP or FTP can create or delete a text file in a shared folder.

However, there is an error when I try to rename the `ABC.txt` file to `XYZ.txt` when using SFTP:

[image]

Using FTP can rename the file. Both SFTP or FTP can delete the file.

How can I let SFTP rename files too?

UPDATE: SFTP log as:

```
30 OPEN
31 CLOSE
32 OPENDIR
33 READDIR
34 READDIR
35 CLOSE
36 REALPATH
37 REMOVE
38 OPENDIR
39 READDIR
40 READDIR
41 CLOSE
```

The above log includes create file, rename file, shows error (at 37), and after closing the error dialog.

Comment: Can you include CyberDuck log file? Did you try another SFTP client?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl SFTP log added

Comment: OK, I didn't know that CyberDuck has such an useless log. Please try another SFTP client (e.g. FileZilla) and include its log.

Comment: Does that user have the correct permissions on the folder?

Comment: @Nuktu yes, access with same user.

Comment: I know SFTP uses the `RENAME` command, however I am not sure about `FTP`. Can you try using SCP instead or some protocol that might use `MV` instead of `RENAME`?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to just be an old bug in Cyberduck, which has been fixed since v4.8.4 (Mar-18-2016). https://cyberduck.io/changelog/

I finally updated my local copy and now can rename files via SFTP.